# Codeception not found Yii

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2, codeception

I have tried to run unit tests in Yii2 project with using codecept. And received next error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Yii' not found in /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Module/Yii2.php on line 77
```

It's my unit.suite.yml content:

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration

# suite for unit (internal) tests.
# RUN `build` COMMAND AFTER ADDING/REMOVING MODULES.

class_name: CodeGuy
modules:
    enabled: [CodeHelper, Yii2]
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'config/web.php'
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: It looks like namespace problem, BTW this path "/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Module/Yii2.php" looks strange for me. Do you run composer update?

Comment: Sorry, I have recreated project. And now I have problem with installation of codeception over composer http://stackoverflow.com/q/28455369/1035334

Comment: @TomaszKane Ok, Yes, I do. But it has no effect:(

Comment: @TomaszKane I don't know wtf is this, but after I added line "class_exists("\\yii\Yii")" to vendor autoload file, the problem went away.

Comment: what does you web.php file says?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First make sure that you have installed codeception the standard way which is through composer: "codeception/codeception":"*"

You don't need to add it to your unit.suite.yml to load Yii when you run codeception. Just change the _bootstrap.php file you can find at rootfolder/tests/ and add the following lines:

```
<?php

// This is global bootstrap for autoloading

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/console.php');
//
$application = new yii\console\Application( $config );
```

Comment: I am doing the same as you suggested. Still I am getting the same error.
I dont know what to write against configFile in my .yml file

Comment: http://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/Zfv/php-unit-testing-yii2-codeception-codeception-not-found-yii - looks a bit familiar doesn't it..