# Installing Codeception over Composer to Yii2

Tags: php, composer-php, codeception

I have problem with installation Codeception to my Yii2 project.

1) Downloaded composer to the Yii2 project:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

2) Trying install Codeception:

```
php composer.phar require "codeception/codeception:*"
```

Error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 == 2.0.2.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.2].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: OK, I have found a solution here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/61520-using-jquery-111/

Comment: for future reference it is perfectly OK to answer your own question. I have added your answer as a community wiki (i.e. I won't get any points from it)

Comment: @topherkanyuga Thank you) I will bear in my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/61520-using-jquery-111

> Try deleting [the vendor folder] first. fxp plugin caches packages info in order to be faster so it's not possible to downgrade w/o deleting vendor